# Safe to resume High-Performance-Computing applications immediately after new thermal paste?

Tags: cpu, temperature, thermal-paste

I recently applied some new thermal paste to my main server, and am wondering if it is safe to immediately resume high-performance computing applications, or if I need to wait for the paste to "settle" before using the CPU at 100% (I don't overclock it though). I am using an Intel i7 CPU.

Comment: Do read the manual or website of the thermal paste if available. While most pastes will work fine out of the box, some may need a certain amount of time to settle and some may require the computer to cool down and heat up in that period of time.

Comment: The old wax based paste required a few thermal cycles to work at 100%, newer pastes no longer require this break in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. If you notice that the CPU is overheating though, you may want to redo the paste.

Comment: TECHNICALLY this depends on the paste, but practically everything on the market should be fine even without waiting for it to set.

Comment: So it should be fine if I start the HPC application, go away from the computer for a few hours, and it shouldn't degrade the paste?

Comment: Yup, that's how it works.

Comment: I would not think twice about it, no (beyond the usual caveat that you should always keep an eye on your temperatures right after remounting a heatsink just in case it's not on correctly)

Comment: HPC apps have been running for about 5 minutes now (I will accept answer in a minute), and it's so far keeping a steady temperature at 105F.